# cannot call an activity from broadcastreceiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I try to call my main activity from broadcast receiver

using this code:

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName(MainActivity.class.getPackage().toString(),
                MainActivity.class.getName().toString());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

and I get this error:

> 12-06 19:17:19.776: E/AndroidRuntime(29271): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {package com.example.dowantcall/com.example.dowantcall.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

with manifest declaration:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.dowantcall.MainActivity" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
   <!--  android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"> -->
    <intent-filter>

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**edit**

btw, I have tried:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName(MainActivity.class.getPackage().toString(),
            "MainActivity");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

and got the same error:

12-06 19:17:19.776: E/AndroidRuntime(29271): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {package com.example.dowantcall/MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: See the log - {package com.example.dowantcall/com.example.dowantcall.MainActivity};

Comment: You are setting the full package and then the class name also has the full package name.

Comment: no, I have tried the class name only and it didn't work also.

Comment: Did you try the snippet I posted above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: The `package` parameter refers to the `package` value in your manifest which identifies your app in the system. The `Class.getPackage()` returns the actual package where a class is located. You need the first value to tell the system "I am starting this intent by the name of this application.".